# How to call a bot composer skill from a bot created on bot framework SDK V4 built in visual studio?

Tags: botframework

I have created a bot in bit composer and exported it as a skill. But my root bot is created from bot framework SDK V4 inside visual studio. How can I call the skill bot from visual studio into my root bot? Or how can I open skill bot, containing .dialog files in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I call the skill bot from visual studio into my root bot?

You can call the skill from your (consumer/parent) bot, by adding some configuration and logic/code to your bot. Per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/skills-about-skill-consumers?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) article:

As a skill consumer, a root bot includes some additional logic to manage traffic between it and a skill:

- Configuration information for each skill the root uses.
- A conversation ID factory that allows the root to switch back and forth between the conversation it is having with the user and the one it is having with a skill.
- A skill client that can package and forward activities to a skill bot.
- A skill handler that can receive requests and unpack activities from a skill bot.

You can see how this is all done by reviewing one of the skill+consumer samples. I would suggest [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot) if you are developing in .NET.

> Or how can I open skill bot, containing .dialog files in visual
> studio?

Check out [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/adaptive-dialog/09.integrating-composer-dialogs) (not sure if that is exactly what you want to do, but a good start).

Comment: Thanks a ton for this link to the sample. This is exactly what I am trying to do. Let me try this out and see how it goes.

Comment: Hi, I tried the code as per this sample but I am getting an error when loading the adaptive dialog in composer i.e. in this line:

  var dialogResource = resourceExplorer.GetResource("RootDialog.dialog");
  var composerDialog = resourceExplorer.LoadType<AdaptiveDialog>(dialogResource);

 "'RootDialog.dialog error: Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Dialog. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'triggers[0].actions[0].$kind', line 20, position 18."

Comment: @quest I'm getting the same error. Any updates on how to resolve this?